# Display logic in Openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I just wanna know, if it is possible to use `sql/hql` statements for a field's Display Logic in `Openbravo`? 
 I have a field, as check box in a window say, position. In another window, I have a field say manager. Now I need to display the manager field only if position is checked. For some reasons, position is not stored in the session. How can I achieve this ? Share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Auxiliary Inputs** to "inject" new session variables into a screen and to defined the value for these you can use SQL.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can have position field within window where manager field present, but displayed = no
(with same name or different name, used to carry value)

2) When position field checked on 'Position' window, update position field on other window i.e where manager field present
(You may try with eventhandler or trigger, since in position window once position field is checked, it triggers save action)

3) Use @position@ = 'Y' syntax (within manager field contained window)